# Issues with JTable, I can add to the table but can't see all rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Within Netbeans I have created a table and added columns "film" and "director" to it. This works fine, but I can't see the table properly only a small section of the last row, which, although alerts me that all rows have been added. I still can't see them fully.

Code and screenshots are below.

### Code

```
    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
DefaultTableModel MovieTable = (DefaultTableModel) MovieTable.getModel();
 MovieTable.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
                   Column1 ="Film1";
                   Column2 ="Director";
                   MovieTable.addRow(new Object[]{Column1, Column2}); }
```

### Screenshot

[image: Truncated table]

### If it helps at all this table is placed on top of a panel.

Comment: Did you really give your DefaultTableModel variable the same name as your JTable variable? Does that even compile?

Comment: Yes, it does compile. I've changed it and the issue still occurs.

Comment: Use Java naming convention. Variables begin with lower case letters

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: `"If it helps at all this table is placed on top of a panel."` -- not really. I agree with @AndrewThompson, that you need to create and post your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if we're to have a chance of guessing what you could be doing wrong.

Comment: Please don't use 'level 2 header' notation for something that is **not** a level 2 header!  You can get **bold** by wrapping it in double asterisks like `**bold**` or *emphasis* by wrapping in single asterisks like `*emphasis*`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're doing wrong because you have not provided relevant code. But even if you did, it may bot even help because of all the messy code generated by the GUI Builder (I assume that's what you're using). So see below.

Simple step by step tutorial, that *doesn't* replicate your problem. Hope you can gain something from it.

1. Create your `JFrame` form
2. Drag and drop a `JPanel` to the frame. Expand it the size for the frame.
3. Drag and Drop a `JTable` to the panel. There's no need for a `JScrollPane` as GUI builder will automatically wrap your table in a scroll pane.
4. Highlight/select the table in the design view and go to the **Properties** window to the right of the design view.
5. Click the <kbd>...</kbd> located to the right of the **model** property.
6. In the dialog create your model i.e. set the number of rows and columns and name your column headers. Click OK when done.
7. Drag and drop two `JTextFeild`s for the Film and Director columns
8. Drag and drop a `JButton`. Create the `actionPerformed` for that button by right clicking it and select `Event -> action -> actionPerformed`
9. In the auto-generated `actionPerformed` do this.

   ```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
       model.getDataVector().removeAllElements();

       String column1 = jTextField1.getText();
       String column2 = jTextField2.getText();

       model.addRow(new Object[] {column1, column2});
   }
   ```
10. If you just wanted to add row without deleting all the other rows, get rid of

    ```
    model.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
    ```
11. Run your program, add some text to the text field and press the button. Everything should work fine is all these steps above were followed. Works for me every time.